# Visual Studio 2008 shuts down after converting solutions

Tags: visual-studio-2008

VS2008 shuts down right after converting any VS2005 solution.

The solution icon is changed from 8 to 9 but if I try to open the solution it tries to convert it again and then it shuts down (and so forth).

Anyone seen this? Is a re-install the only way to go here?

Comment: SP1 not showing up on the about dialog

Comment: tried to install SP1 got blue screen of death

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you haven't already done so, you may want to review the upgrade log and your EventLog to see if they have any entries that could lead you in the right direction.

Sorry, I would have just added this suggestion as a comment but I don't have a high enough reputation.

Comment: this is what I think happened - seems to happen only on upgrades from 2005

Answer (score 0):

Trying hooking up a debugger (ie another instance of Visual Studio) to it, (using Tools - Attach to Process). Optionally set 'break on exceptions' (Ctrl-Alt-E) just before starting the conversion.

Hopefully this will break into the debugger giving you a clue what's crashing.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen it before.  I always end up manually moving my project over.

Comment: what do you mean with 'manually'? do you manually edit solution files and all? sounds PAINFUL

Comment: if its a c++ proj, for example, i'd create new c++ proj, add existing files, select all my headers and c++ files, then edit my proj variables and so forth

Comment: turned out a problem upgrading from 2005 ... puzzled - wiped it off and re-installed from scratch